Design principles for good UX for 360° animations in VR?
I'm looking to create 360 animations as a VR experience. I don't have experience with Blender, development on VR, or animation creation. The main challenge is going to be creating animations that look good even when viewed in fully immersive 360 environment. I looked at some UX design principles for VR developers, e.g., this one: https://principles.design/examples/designing-for-virtual-reality
That seems to be for VR games. Do those same principles apply for animations? If you guys have any further resources, that'd be great!
